# Mostrar primeiro e último registro de cada data

Tags: php, query, mysqli, loop, data

Gostaria de buscar no banco de dados todos os registros de acordo com o "MEDICO" entre duas datas `DATA_INICIAL` e `DATA_FINAL` Sem repetir registros do dia.

**RESULTADO ATUAL:**

```
BRUNO BARBOSAS   02/04/2018 12:18   02/04/2018 12:18
BRUNO BARBOSAS   02/04/2018 12:22   02/04/2018 12:22
BRUNO BARBOSAS   09/04/2018 08:26   09/04/2018 08:26
BRUNO BARBOSAS   09/04/2018 08:30   09/04/2018 08:30
```

**GOSTARIA QUE APENAS MOSTRASSE:**

```
BRUNO BARBOSAS   02/04/2018 12:18   02/04/2018 12:22
BRUNO BARBOSAS   09/04/2018 08:26   09/04/2018 08:30
```

**CÓDIGO:**

```
$nome= $_POST['nome'];
$data_i = $_POST['data_inicio'];
$data_f = $_POST['data_fim'];

$consulta= "SELECT * FROM $tabela 
          WHERE medico = '$medico' 
          AND data >= '$data_i' 
          AND data <= '$data_f' ";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);

while($rows_registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    echo $rows_registro['nome'];
    echo $rows_registro['data']; //Aqui tem que vir o PRIMEIRO registro do dia sem repetir
    echo $rows_registro['data']; //Aqui tem que vir o ULTIMO registro do dia sem repetir
}
```

Após buscar entre as duas datas gostaria de mostrar o primeiro registro e o ultimo pra cada DIA sem repetir como mostra o exemplo acima de como gostaria o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta um

```
SELECT
       MIN(data) AS primeiro,
       MAX(data) AS ultimo
FROM
       tabela
WHERE
       ... (condiçoes aqui)
GROUP BY
       DATE(data) -- extrai só a parte da data para agrupar por dia
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3d96e/1)**

Assim você terá os resultados em duas colunas, e poderá exibir assim:

```
if ($rows_registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    echo $medico;
    echo $rows_registro['primeiro'];
    echo $rows_registro['ultimo'];
}
```

Agora, isso se o DB estiver com as datas armazenadas corretamente. Se não estiver, tem que arrumar o DB.

Tem umas gambiarras que o pessoal faz pra converter na hora da consulta, sendo que formatação deve ser na hora da exibição apenas, mas não vou entrar nessa linha por aqui para evitar incentivar a criação de problemas.

A data estando no formato certo, você pode formatar para exibição assim:

```
DATE_FORMAT(MIN(data), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS primeiro
```

Desta forma não estará usando conversão na hora da busca, apenas na saída.

Veja a formatação funcionando no **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3d96e/2)**

Comment: Perfeito, era isso o que realmente queria, consegui trazer os resultados certinho, so tive um problema para encaixar na condição onde so irá buscar quando for igual ao NOME escolhido e DATA_INICIAL e DATA_FINAL. Tentei com usando >= AND <= alem de BETWEEN:<br>

<code> WHERE nome= '$nome'  AND data >= '$data_i'  AND data <= '$data_f' "</code>

O resultado fica em branco mesmo colocando a data existente no banco de dados, o que será que está acontecendo. Só falta isso pra terminar meu projeto.

Comment: @profnv exemplo com faixa de datas e nome: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3d96e/3

Comment: perfeito, valeu mesmo, salvou o dia

Answer (score -1):

Uma abordagem é você realizar uma query onde você agrupe pela data.

```
SELECT count(*), DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m-01") AS month FROM tabela GROUP BY month
```

De uma olhada em  [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) do MySQL.